# How to remove multiple axis from numpy array using np.squeeze?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array of shape `(1,1,51200,50)`, I want to reduce it to `(51200,50)`

I did the below

```
arr1 = np.squeeze(arr, axis=0)
arr2 = np.squeeze(arr1, axis=0)
```

Now I get the desired shape

```
$arr2.shape
(51200,50)
```

Is there a simple way to do it, instead of 2 steps here? Please help.

Comment: `np.squeeze(arr)` ?

Comment: Wow That worked!! :) Thanks @MichaelSzczesny! :)

Comment: `axis` can be a tuple, `np.squeeze(arr,axis=(0,1))`.  Read the docs!

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj ! I had tried that, but had forgotten to put the brackets. My mistake.